# VS Code: "Unable to read file" after directory change

Tags: visual-studio-code

After moving my project to another folder, the VS Code debugger tries to open the files in their old path when an exception is thrown, resulting in a "Unable to read file" error in VS Code. How to fix this?

This is my launch.json file:

```
"configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/Project.Host/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Project.Host.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/src/Project.Host",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "action": "openExternally",
                "pattern": "^\\s*Now listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)"
            },
            "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
            }
        }
```

Comment: Close all the open file tabs, maybe some of them are still refering to the old non existant ones. Also check if all the folders listed in the launch actually exist.

Comment: Still not working. Even deleting the .vscode folder doesn't fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that there are some old breakpoints in my debugger so I removed them, without breakpoints the debugger worked just fine, but whenever I tried to add a new breakpoint it referred to an old cpp file location.

Ended up reinstalling vscode -_- it helped but I don't think everyone can just reinstall vscode when there's a problem. For some reason, some internal vscode settings didn't refresh when I moved the folder with the code to a new location.